# How to configure shell commands to be selectable for running?

Tags: mac, shell, visual-studio-code

I have many projects and I would like to have list of the project visible somewhere on my Mac, and openable on-click. Each project can be opened with a shell command.

I use VSCode to work with projects, so the commands looks like `code [path/to/my/project]`.

I tried to create a file on Desktop with extension `sh`, with a command that opens my project.
If I run the command directly in terminal, it works well, i.e it opens VSCode. But, if I click the file, it opens terminal, the terminal blinks, and that's it.

I know I can create aliases for terminal and use them, but it is hard for me to remember alias for each project.

Also I know VSCode remembers recent folders. However, list of my projects is bigger than VSCode can fit to the list of recents.

Comment: _"If I run the command directly in terminal […]"_ - how exactly? Do the files have the executable bit set and a correct shebang?

Comment: I open mu iTerm, type `code /my/project/folder`, and VSCode opens this folder. I do not know what is 'executable bit set and a correct shebang`. Could you clarify, please?

Answer (score 1):

I created the alias `profile` for `code /Users/polinach/.bash_profile`, and aliases for all my projects.
So my steps are:

1. Run `profile`
2. See project name
3. Run `project_name`